# How do I generate an A4-sized single card in squib?

Tags: ruby, dsl, squib

I'm trying to use Squib to generate a map for a boardgame by printing one "card" which is the size of an entire A4 sheet of paper.

There must be some default in Squib that is cropping the resulting images and text, however, so that only a portion of it is visible.

Here is some sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
require 'squib'   

Squib::Deck.new cards: 1, layout: [] do
  rect x: 0, y: 0, width: 3457, height: 2438, fill_color: 'BLUE'
  circle x: 1728, y: 1218 , radius: 1218, fill_color: 'RED'    
  save_pdf file: 'maps_1.pdf' 
end
```

At 300 dpi, a landscape A4 piece of paper should be 3457x2438 pixels, so this ought to display a blue box with a red circle, filling the page. Instead it displays a poker-card-sized chunk of that image in the upper left hand corner:

[resulting pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frYPZ.png)

The result is much the same if I use millimeters, with a sprue:

```
require 'squib'   

Squib::Deck.new cards: 1, layout: [] do
   rect x: 0, y: 0, width: '295mm', height: '208mm', fill_color: 'BLUE'
   circle x: '147.5mm', y: '104mm' , radius: '104mm', fill_color: 'RED'    
   save_pdf file: 'maps_1.pdf', sprue: 'layouts/map-sprue.yml'
end
```

Sprue:

```
---
sheet_width: 297mm
sheet_height: 210mm
card_width: 295.0mm
card_height: 208.0mm
cards:
- x: 0.0mm
  y: 0.0mm
crop_line:
  lines:
  - type: :vertical
    position: 0.0mm
  - type: :vertical
    position: 295.0mm
  - type: :horizontal
    position: 0.0mm
  - type: :horizontal
    position: 208.0mm
```

Does anyone know what is forcing squib only to address a portion of the A4 page?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `width` and `height` as parameters to `Squib::Deck.new`

To make your "card" the entire size of an A4 page, use something like this:

```rb
Squib::Deck.new(width: '210mm', height: '297mm') do
end
```

**HOWEVER** If you are planning on *printing* to an A4 page I recommend making it a tad smaller so that your printer doesn't autoscale or cut things off. My printer does fine with 6mm margin, probably something like 200x290.

You probably don't need sprues in this situation.